# Audio file tagging/renaming

Tags: windows, audio, mp4, tags

I would like to properly tag my music collection in the following way:

Filename:

Artist - Song Title - Key(Original Key) - BPM - Genre

Tags:

The tags match above(each token above is a id tag).

Is there any software out there that can automate this? I am currently doing this by hand and it is slow(mainly getting the key and bpm of the song).

Even if I could just fill in the tag's for Genre it would speed up things(Really looking for general and specific, e.g., Rock(Classic), Country(Swing), etc...).

Obviously once the tags are filled in it is easy to generate the file name.

Comment: There are lots of tagging utilities available, including I'm sure for your OS of choice (which you neglected to mention). Which ones have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried the musicbrain one and I've tried others in the past. Nothing, as least as far as I could tell, could do specifically what I wanted(at least not without learning a bunch of stuff). It seems some can do key and some can do bpm(usually by calculation but usually off/wrong).

Comment: Sometimes you just have to learn a bunch of stuff to get unusual things done. MusicBrainz Picard should be able to do this probably with scripting.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me too, I use Boilsoft 3GP/iPod/PSP/MP4 Converter which can easily solve the problem.

Here is the link: http://www.boilsoft.com